# Can't see any disk in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS installation guide

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I recently ordered a [HP Omen desktop gaming PC](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/omen-30l-desktop-gt13-0380t-2h4a2av-1), it has 2 disks (1T SSD + 2T HDD), and pre-installed with Windows 11, all works fine.

I need to refresh it to **Ubuntu 18** (dual boot is **not** necessary) as a Machine Learning training PC.

Firstly, I turned off Windows **FastBoot** in Power option by `set when click power off, turn off machine`, also ran the Windows command: `powercfg -h off`

And went into BIOS, the only option seems related to boot is `SafeBoot`, whatever I turn on or off it, the result are the same. And **there's no AHCI option and etc** in BIOS menu.

I made a Ubuntu 18 USB drive for installation, but could not see any disks show in guide, but only the USB drive:
[image]

Then, I went into live mode, opened the terminal, tried these commands:

```
cat /etc/os-release
sudo fdisk -l
sudo lsblk
```

as I understand, still can't get disks at all, these are the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

also, the `Disks` and `Gparted` shows no luck:
[image]

[image]

Could you help?

Comment: There should be an "Erase Disk and Install" option before you get to the screen in your first screenshot. Based on your question this seems like the appropriate action. Is there any reason that is not working for you?

Comment: Is Ubuntu 18.04 an absolute requirement? If you have a relatively recent model, it may not have the necessary hardware support to handle the PCIe bus ...

Comment: @Nmath no, there's no such a option of `Erase Disk and Install`, before the selecting disk page, I can see only `Language` , `Local`  and `Updates and other software`.

Comment: Use the "Try Ubuntu" option when booting and run the "Disks" application. Your disk should show up on the left. Select it and choose "Format".  This will erase the disk and give it a new partition table. Use the GPT partition scheme. Then restart the installation.  I agree that you should use Ubuntu 20.04 as it is more likely to be compatible with new hardware.  Let us know if that works

Comment: @Nmath I uploaded more pictures, seems no luck in `Disks` and `GParted`.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for reminding, updated the title.

Comment: @matigo as the Toolkit indicates the OS should be `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, so I'll stay with that for a while.

Comment: If 18.04 cannot support the hardware, then sticking with it seems suboptimal. If very specific libraries and whatnot are required, sometimes a Docker container or other virtualization layer is infinitely better than working with partially-supported hardware ...

Comment: Did you shut down Windows completely? Keep in mind that if "Fast Startup" is enabled in Windows, it does not fully shut down because that feature is actually a hybrid suspend. If Windows is not fully shut down it can prevent other operating systems from using those drives.  I agree, again, that you should use a newer release for newer hardware. I'm confident that the software ypu believe will only work on 18.04 will also work on 20.04 but you haven't given us any details about why you think you need 18.04. That's a different problem (or likely, not a problem at all)

Answer (score 0):

I have to change to `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`, and all disks can show in installation wizard now.
This is may not the answer, but I'll leave it here.